# How to get the list of all available timezone using moment-timezone

Tags: timezone, momentjs

I am trying to get the list of all the available timezones using moment-timezone in node js like this -

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
var timeZones = moment.tz.names();
console.log(timeZones);
```

I am getting the timezones in this format -

```
'Europe/Mariehamn',
'Europe/Minsk',
'Europe/Monaco',
'Europe/Moscow',
'Europe/Nicosia',
'Europe/Oslo',
'Europe/Paris',
'Europe/Podgorica',
'Europe/Prague',
'Europe/Riga',
'Europe/Rome',
```

But I want to get the timezones in this format -

```
(GMT +01:00) Africa/Brazzaville
(GMT +01:00) Africa/Casablanca
(GMT +01:00) Africa/Douala
(GMT +01:00) Africa/El_Aaiun
(GMT +01:00) Africa/Kinshasa
(GMT +01:00) Africa/Lagos
(GMT +01:00) Africa/Libreville
(GMT +01:00) Africa/Luanda
(GMT +01:00) Africa/Malabo
(GMT +01:00) Africa/Ndjamena
(GMT +01:00) Africa/Niamey
```

How do I get ?

Comment: Which offset are you wanting to show?  The standard offset for the current year?  The *current* offset (which may or may not be the standard offset), The offset in effect at a particular point in time?  What function the list going to perform in your application?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is no straight way of getting in the format you want, directly from `moment-timezone`.

Try like below.

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
var timeZones = moment.tz.names();
var offsetTmz=[];

for(var i in timeZones)
{
    offsetTmz.push(" (GMT"+moment.tz(timeZones[i]).format('Z')+") " + timeZones[i]);
}
```

Now, `offsetTmz` is an array of strings in the format you want.

This is how I am using it.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Note that this is going to give you the offset NOW. That may not be the offset during standard time. It will change in any timezone that observes DST.

Answer (score 6):

Based on @Shrabanee answer and according to @Tenz comment  - this is my solution with es6 Template literals and with sorting the list by the GMT + number instead of the timezone name:

```
    timeZones = momentTimezone.tz.names();
    let offsetTmz=[];

    for(let i in timeZones)
    {
        offsetTmz.push(`(GMT${moment.tz(timeZones[i]).format('Z')}) ${timeZones[i]}`);
    }

    this.timeZoneNames = offsetTmz.sort();
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on [the answer by Erez Liberman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50896710/407953) and [the answer by Matt Johnson about trimming the list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35921933/407953) I would like to add mine as a full `Typescript` class, that sorts timezones with negative offset in  reverse order

```typescript
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';

export class TimezoneData {
    tzName: string;
    tzPresentationName: string;
}

export class TimezoneUtils {

    public static getTimezonesNames(): TimezoneData[] {
        const arr: TimezoneData[] = [];
        const names = moment.tz.names();
        for (const name of names) {
            if ((name.indexOf('/') < 0 && name !== 'UTC') || name.startsWith('Etc/')) {
                continue;
            }
            const data = new TimezoneData();
            data.tzName = name;
            data.tzPresentationName = moment.tz(name).format('Z');
            arr.push(data);
        }
        arr.sort((a, b) => {
            if (a.tzPresentationName === b.tzPresentationName) {
                if (a.tzName === 'UTC') {
                    return -1;
                }
                return a.tzName === b.tzName ? 0 : (a.tzName > b.tzName ? 1 : -1);
            }
            const afc = a.tzPresentationName.charAt(0);
            const bfc = b.tzPresentationName.charAt(0);
            if (afc === '-') {
                if (bfc === '+') {
                    return -1;
                }
                return a.tzPresentationName > b.tzPresentationName ? -1 : 1;
            }
            if (bfc === '-') {
                return 1;
            }
            return a.tzPresentationName > b.tzPresentationName ? 1 : -1;
        });
        arr.forEach(a => a.tzPresentationName = `${a.tzName} (GMT ${a.tzPresentationName})`);
        return arr;
    }
}
```